# How to remove duplicate rows as well as old records in Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I search through the net and didn't find answer for this kind.

I have table emp_master_data, which have many columns but I want to use few columns to filter the data ( select query) and then after analyzing, I want to delete those records.

The filter should be applied on three columns emp_card_no, emp_id , enrollment_exp_dt.  An employee can be enrolled multiple times , which means you'll have multiple records with same emp_no, emp_id and same/different enrollment_exp_dt.

Now , I need to do this:

Remove the duplicate records if there are multiple records with same enrollment_exp_dt, emp_card_no and emp_id.

If in case I have multiple records for same employee but different enrollment_exp_dt , then remove the old records and keep only the latest record ( doesn't have to be >sysdate).

Please let me know the best way I could do. I did try doing this but doesn't solve all the problems.

`SELECT *
FROM brm_staging A
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM brm_staging
  WHERE enrollment_exp_dt = A.enrollment_exp_dt 
  and emp_id= A.emp_id
  and emp_card_no =A.emp_card_no
  AND ROWID < A.ROWID
);`

Comment: how to distinguish between rows with same enrollment_exp_dt, emp_card_no and emp_id? i mean, is there this rowId which is unique?

Comment: @Apostolos each employee uniquely identified by emp_id will have One card active , which means exp dt > sysdate. So, emp_id ,card no and exp date together identify one row uniquely. did I answer your question?

Comment: that's what i didnt get. since these identify one row uniquely, how can you say 'Remove the duplicate records if there are multiple records with same enrollment_exp_dt, emp_card_no and emp_id'?  am i missing sth here? i'll read it again :)

Comment: unless you have this rowid column and among duplicates, you delete all except for the one with biggest rowid

Comment: Let me explain, the duplicate rows is due is code logic error and not the actual expected behavior. I ran queries are noticed this. E.g Row 1 (emp_id = 101, card no= 77153 , exp = 10/22/2013), Row 2 (  emp_id = 101, card no= 77153 , exp = 10/22/2013) this is case 1, same rows. 

Row 1 (emp_id = 102, card no= 77154 , exp = 11/22/2013) Row 2( emp_id = 102, card no= 77154 , exp = 11/22/2013 ) and Row 3 ( emp_id = 102, card no= 77154 , exp = 11/1/2013 ) this is case 2, now for this case we should have the latest which means Row 1 and Row 2 qualifies since their exp is later than Row 3.

Comment: This table should have only one record, so remove Row 2 and keep only Row1.

Comment: i'll post an answer (i'm thinking how to write it) for the second senario, because for the first and having only these three columns, i dont know how to do it

Comment: sorry, i got stuck :(

Comment: see my answer. not quite sure it's working. if not, please let me know so as to delete it. thnx!

Answer (score 1):

i got really complicated. can you try the select statement first before deleting and see if this is working? (this is for second senario)

```
DELETE FROM YOUR_TABLE T1 
INNER JOIN (
SELECT T2.* FROM YOUR_TABLE T2,
(SELECT EMP_ID, CARD_NO, COUNT(*) FROM
YOUR_TABLE 
GROUP BY EMP_ID, CARD_NO
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) T3
WHERE T2.EMP_ID=T3.EMP_ID AND T2.CARD_NO = T3.CARD_NO AND
T2.ENROLLMENT_EXP_DT NOT IN (SELECT MAX(T4.ENROLLMENT_EXP_DT)
FROM YOUR_TABLE T4) T5 ON
T1.EMP_ID=T5.EMP_ID AND T1.CARD_NO=T5.CARD_NO AND T1.ENROLLMENT_EXP_DT=T5.ENROLLMENT_EXO_DT
```

(EDIT) i think this work too (more simplified)

```
DELETE FROM YOUR_TABLE T1 
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT T2.* FROM YOUR_TABLE T2,
(SELECT EMP_ID, CARD_NO, COUNT(*) FROM
YOUR_TABLE 
GROUP BY EMP_ID, CARD_NO
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) T3
WHERE T2.EMP_ID=T3.EMP_ID AND T2.CARD_NO = T3.CARD_NO AND
T2.ENROLLMENT_EXP_DT NOT IN (SELECT MAX(T4.ENROLLMENT_EXP_DT)
FROM YOUR_TABLE T4)
```